# MySQL queries in PhP script not working, but same queries work in the mysql shell

Tags: php, mysql, insert

My `php/mysql` connection statement is:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'apacheaccount', 'password', 'database')
            or die ('Unable to connect');
```

My query execution statement is:

```
 $sqli = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stringVariableContainingQuery);
```

As root, in the `MySQL` shell, I gave ALL privileges to the various versions of the account in the `USERS` table in the database, then flushed privileges.

In Php pages, `SELECT` statements will work, but `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements do not.

However, the exact same `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements will work in the `MySQL` shell.

I am aware of SQL injection; this is just a test database for an assignment at school and has no sensitive data.

I am running Apache and MySQL on CentOS. No, I'm not running a version of Windows. Yes, I am aware of the difference between `php_mysql` and `php_mysqli` extensions.

What is the problem here?

Comment: where are the queries??

Comment: What is the output of `mysqli_error($mysqli);` after the query?

Comment: Can you mix procedural and OO mysqli commands like that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you out.

I recommend for testing purposes changing yor mysqli for the following:

```
$sqli=mysqli_query($mysqli,$stringVariableContainingQuery) or print_r(mysqli_errors());
```

This way you can check the response from the Sql instead of going blind